# MutableState value could not be changed in if expression

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I find that MutableState value could not be changed in if expression.
Examples:

Example1, It works.

```
var state1 by remember {
    mutableStateOf(0)
}
Button(onClick = {
    state1 = 1
}) {
    Text(text = state1.toString())
}
```

Example2. Can build but not work. state2 is always 0, although the button has been clicked.

```
var state2 by remember {
    mutableStateOf(0)
}
Button(onClick = {
    if (state2 == 0) state2 = 1
    if (state2 == 1) state2 = 2
    if (state2 == 2) state2 = 0
}) {
    Text(text = state2.toString())
}
```

Example3. It works.

```
var state3 by remember {
    mutableStateOf(0)
}
Button(onClick = {
    state3 = when (state3) {
        0 -> 1
        1 -> 2
        2 -> 0
        else -> 2
    }
}) {
    Text(text = state3.toString())
}
```

I am very want to know what's the differences between Example2 and Example3 and why Example 2 not work. And how I can change the MutableState value in if expression.

Comment: In Example 2, insert `else` in front of the second two `if` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with state 0

```
if (state2 == 0) state2 = 1
```

`state2 == 0` is true so state2 is set to 1

```
if (state2 == 1) state2 = 2
```

state2 was set to 1 in the line above, remember? `state2 == 1` is true already so state2 is set to 2

```
if (state2 == 2) state2 = 0
```

because state2 was set to 2, this is also true. state2 is set to 0

So, it works. It works too well, goes through every value and loops back to 0. This is because you forgot `else` before every if.

So, the moral of the story is: use `when/switch`

Answer (score 0):

In example 3 the when statement stops after the first match so it should stop evaluating after it matches the state3 == 0. Your second example seems to work as written.  The final expression changes state2 back to zero.

Answer (score 0):

| recommended way is to use WHEN especially when we have cascading logic or using if else... if you trying to modify a same value

```
if (state2 == 0) {
    state2 = 1
} else if (state2 == 1) {
    state2 = 2
} else if (state2 == 2) {
    state2 = 0
}
```